# SQL Generating subversion number (Series Generation)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, asp.net-ajax

Below is my table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sample](
    [BoardId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserCode] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [Desc] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL)
```

short description about the table, User can opt to save "Desc"[User info as per the user] as a seperate version each time. I would like to generate a version number for each subVersion being created. The parentId field holds the PK ID for which the subversion is being created.
For example, some records below.

```
boardID        UserCode     Desc       Version   ParentID  CreatedOn       ModifiedOn
1              12343jhgs    blah blah    1          0        ---            ---
2              12343jhgs    blah blah    1          1        ---            ---
3              12343jhgs    blah blah    2          1        ---            ---
4              73627ggjh    lol lol ol   1          0        ---            ---
```

Hope you are getting the idea, for each subversion created i would like to generate a Version number that increments.

Comment: Given your sample data, what would be your required output?

Comment: The sample data is the output, i should have explained more. Record 1 is the sample data. from record 2 you can see they have parentId indicating they are subversions, so for each subversion the version number increments. It is this subversion number generation that i wanted the code for.

Comment: @EdHarper I don't know if this is a elegant solution but seems to get me the answer. Ed could you correct me SELECT  CASE(SELECT COUNT(*)) WHEN '0' THEN '1' ELSE MAX(version) + 1 END FROM SAMPLE WHERE parentId = '2' [OR someother value]

Comment: @Deeptechtons - I'm not sure your code will give you the desired output, but what you're asking should be possible. In you sample data, how is the order of `boardId` 2 and 3 determined?

Comment: @EdHarper BoardId is increment identity column with seed value of 1. The records with board id 2 and 3 were created to test  the subversion process but ended up getting same version number for each new record. Hence this post came into existence on SO. right now it is done at design level where i use DataView to get the subversion records and then get their count and increment by 1.

Comment: @Deeptechtons - what I'm trying to find out is how you know the order is `BoardId` 2 then `BoardId` 3, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Also, which version of SQL server?

Comment: @EdHarper as explained above they are auto increment columns, they just increment for each record. I use Sql Server Express 2005.

Comment: @Deeptechtons - I'm sorry I'm not being clear - how do you detemine that `BoardId` 2 version = 1 and `BoardId` 3 version  = 2 (rather than the other way around)?

Comment: @EdHarper well that was my question,( i wanted sql to generate me version number incrementally for each subversion save). If a first subversion is created then version number = 1, if second subversion is created then version number = 2.[btw by subversions i mean records which have parentId] i hope you understood that i wanted subversion just by changing the version number for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example based on your sample data. I have assumed that the version number of instances of `boardId` with the same `ParentId` is determined by order of insertion.

**EDIT** - re-reading your description and comments I realised that the parent and first child having version 1 was intentional:

```
DECLARE @Sample TABLE 
(
    [BoardId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [UserCode] [NVARCHAR](20) NOT NULL,
    [Desc] [NVARCHAR](100) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [INT] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [DATETIME] ,
    [ModifiedOn] [DATETIME]
)

INSERT @Sample
(boardID,UserCode,[Desc],ParentID)
VALUES
(1,'12343jhgs','blah blah',0),
(2,'12343jhgs','blah blah',1),
(3,'12343jhgs','blah blah',1),
(4,'73627ggjh','lol lol ol',0)


;WITH recCTE
AS
(
    SELECT  boardID,UserCode,[Desc],ParentID, BoardID AS TopParent, 0 as versionModifier
    FROM    @Sample
    WHERE   ParentId = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  s.boardID,s.UserCode,s.[Desc],s.ParentID, r.TopParent, -1 as versionModifier
    FROM    @Sample AS s 
    JOIN    recCTE AS r 
    ON      r.BoardId = s.ParentId
)
SELECT  boardID,UserCode,[Desc],ParentID, BoardID, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TopParent
                            ORDER BY    boardId
                          )   + versionModifier AS [Version]
FROM recCTE
```